why I got SMTP authentication error with mailtrap?
I am currently working on a website. And I want to add an email sending function to the website.
I'm trying to test this using mailtrap (https://mailtrap.io).
But I got the following error message:
Fatal error: Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. in C:\xampp\htdocs\oktatas\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php:2265 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\oktatas\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php(2062): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpConnect(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\oktatas\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php(1689): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Thu, 27 J...', 'Send HTML E...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\oktatas\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php(1523): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->postSend() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\oktatas\kuldes.php(56): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send() #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\oktatas\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php on line 2265
I wrote the following code:
<?php
$phpmailer = new PHPMailer(true);
$phpmailer->isSMTP();
$phpmailer->Host = 'sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io';
$phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$phpmailer->Port = 2525;
$phpmailer->Username = 'ba339bab3fb68d';
$phpmailer->Password = '********6030';

$phpmailer->setFrom('info@mailtrap.io', 'Mailtrap');
$phpmailer->addReplyTo('info@mailtrap.io', 'Mailtrap');

$phpmailer->addAddress('info@mailtrap.io');
$phpmailer->Subject = 'Test Email via Mailtrap SMTP using PHPMailer';
$phpmailer->isHTML(true);
$mailContent = "<h1>Send HTML Email using SMTP in PHP</h1>
    <p>This is a test email I’m sending using SMTP mail server with PHPMailer.</p>";
$phpmailer->Body = $mailContent;
if(!$phpmailer->send()){
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $phpmailer->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}

I changed the php.ini file several times, but I got the same error message again.
UPDATE: I got the following error message in debug mode:
2024-06-27 16:50:32 Auth method requested: UNSPECIFIED
2024-06-27 16:50:32 Auth methods available on the server: PLAIN,LOGIN,CRAM-MD5
2024-06-27 16:50:32 Requested auth method not available:
2024-06-27 16:50:32 Auth method selected: CRAM-MD5
2024-06-27 16:50:32 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH CRAM-MD5
2024-06-27 16:50:33 SMTP INBOUND: "334 PDY3NzI0MDgxOC4xNzE5NTA3MDMzQHNtdHAubWFpbHRyYXAuaW8+"
2024-06-27 16:50:33
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 PDY3NzI0MDgxOC4xNzE5NTA3MDMzQHNtdHAubWFpbHRyYXAuaW8+
2024-06-27 16:50:33
CLIENT -> SERVER: YmEzMzliYWIzZmI2OGQgYjFiNzU4ODcwNTNlZjVkZjlkMjMwZTk4ZDQ1YTE1NWI=
2024-06-27 16:50:33 SMTP INBOUND: "535 5.7.0 Invalid credentials"
2024-06-27 16:50:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.0 Invalid credentials
2024-06-27 16:50:33 SMTP ERROR: Username command failed: 535 5.7.0 Invalid credentials
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2024-06-27 16:50:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2024-06-27 16:50:33 SMTP INBOUND: ""
2024-06-27 16:50:33 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2024-06-27 16:50:33 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
2024-06-27 16:50:33 Connection: closed
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Is there any specific reason that you don't want to use the official Mailtrap API and/or SDK? Have you enabled debug to see the more specific error?

Per their documentation, that error means that a "combination of login and password was not found". If this does not match your expectation, it might be best to contact Mailtrap directly.
